# How to remove a div that is not clicked

Tags: javascript

I want to remove `basket One`div if  `basket Two` div is clicked and vice versa.

```js
var basketClass = document.getElementsByClassName("basketClass");
var basketOne = document.getElementById("basketOne");
var basketTwo = document.getElementById("basketTwo");

for (var i = 0; i < basketClass.length; i++) {
  basketClass[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target === basketOne || basketTwo) {
      //removeSibling(basketOne||basketTwo);
      //want to remove basketone if basketTwo is clicked and vice versa
    }
  })
};
```

```html
<div id="basketOne" class="basketClass">Basket One </div>
<div id="basketTwo" class="basketClass">Basket Two </div>
```

Comment: Other people have given good answers, but I have a comment about something you need to be careful about. `if (event.target === basketOne || basketTwo)` doesn't mean what you probably think it means. Such a comparison should be written `if (event.target === basketOne || event.target === basketTwo)`. As long as basketTwo exists, then `(event.target === basketOne || basketTwo)` is ALWAYS true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use the `event.target` attribute to get the clicked element and make the necessary comparison.
- You can use the function **[`ChildNode.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)**.
- This condition is not ok:

```
if (event.target === basketOne || basketTwo) {...}
                                  ^
```

In that condition is missing the left operand:

```
if (event.target === basketOne || event.target === basketTwo) {...}
```

```js
var basketClass = document.getElementsByClassName("basketClass");
var basketOne = document.getElementById("basketOne");
var basketTwo = document.getElementById("basketTwo");

for (var i = 0; i < basketClass.length; i++) {
  basketClass[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target === basketOne) {
      basketTwo.remove();
    }

    if (event.target === basketTwo) {
      basketOne.remove();
    }
  })
};
```

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed green;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<div id="basketOne" class="basketClass">Basket One </div>
<div id="basketTwo" class="basketClass">Basket Two </div>
```

Comment: I liked all the answers from all posters.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that remove div means to hide the div:

```
var basketClass = document.getElementsByClassName("basketClass");
var basketOne = document.getElementById("basketOne");
var basketTwo = document.getElementById("basketTwo");

for (var i = 0; i < basketClass.length; i++) {
  basketClass[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
    if(event.target === basketOne){
      basketOne.style.display = "block";
      basketTwo.style.display = "none";
    }else if(event.target === basketTwo){
      basketTwo.style.display = "block";
      basketOne.style.display = "none";
    }
  })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually remove the div you won't be able to reuse it, somehow. So assuming you mean 'hide', not 'remove from the DOM'.

You *don't need to actually check what is clicked*:

```js
var basketClass= document.getElementsByClassName("basketClass");

for (var i = 0; i < basketClass.length; i++) {
  basketClass[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
    click(event);
    this.style.display = 'block';
  })
};

function click(event) {
  for (var i = 0; i < basketClass.length; i++) {
    basketClass[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="basketClass">One</div>
<div class="basketClass">Two</div>
```

This just assumes you can set everything to invisible, and later make the one actually clicked in the event visible again. This scales to an unlimited number of baskets.

Answer (score 0):

Place both the basket elements into an array. Then, a simple ternary `if` statement that targets the right element in the array to remove is all you need.

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("parent"); // Get reference to basket parent

// Put both basket elements into an array
var baskets = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".basketClass")); 

// Loop over the array
baskets.forEach(function(basket) {
  // Set up click event handler
  basket.addEventListener('click', removeBasket);
});

function removeBasket(event){
    // Remove the other element in the array
    parent.removeChild(this === baskets[0] ? baskets[1] : baskets[0]);
    // Remove the event binding because target basket is now removed.
    this.removeEventListener("click", removeBasket); 
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="basketOne" class="basketClass">Basket One </div>
  <div id="basketTwo" class="basketClass">Basket Two </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Deke Updated answer to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't actually want to remove the node from the DOM but just hide it, you can try:

```js
var basketOne = document.getElementById("basketOne"),
  basketTwo = document.getElementById("basketTwo");

[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('basketClass'), function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    basketOne.style.display = e.target === basketOne ? 'block' : 'none';
    basketTwo.style.display = e.target === basketTwo ? 'block' : 'none';
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="basketClass" id="basketOne">Basket ONE</div>
<div class="basketClass" id="basketTwo">Basket TWO</div>
```

Note: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object, so you can iterate through it with `forEach`.